# How can i return the id of the last updated record in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, pdo, sql-update, lastinsertid

I am using PDO to connect to MySQL. When even I add new record to the database and want to know the id of the last record added then I call the `lastinsertid()` built in PDO. However, this time I am trying to return the last updated record. According to my knowledge [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) should return the last updated ID as well.

> Returns the ID of the last inserted row, or the last value from a sequence object

But in my case it does not return what it should. It returns the value `0`.
How can I configure `lastinsertid()` to return the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value of the record that was updated by the update query?

Comment: Err... What field you are using to identify the row when updating it?

Comment: the ID is called phone_call_id and it is AUTO_INCREMENT value which should be returned on the update

Comment: Why do you want it returned if you already know it?

Comment: I don't know the id value i update based on a giving criteria. So if no records were found that fits that criteria I want to insert a new record. I am using the id value to determine if the update took place or not.

Comment: @Your Common Sense, sorry, I miss understood your first question. But my second answer clarified what I use to update the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I count not find a way to return last updated id. But what I have done is to accomplish what I am looking for is by checking the `countRow` method as it return the total effected rows.

So I do an update if a record is found then done. if there was no record found I do an insert.

Thanks